# Need help speeding up a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I need a query that quickly shows the articles within a particular module (a subset of articles) that a user has NOT uploaded a PDF for. The query I am using below takes about 37 seconds, given there are 300,000 articles in the Article table, and 6,000 articles in the Module.

```
SELECT * 
FROM article a 
INNER JOIN article_module_map amm ON amm.article=a.id 
WHERE amm.module = 2 AND
    a.id NOT IN ( 
        SELECT afm.article 
        FROM article_file_map afm 
        INNER JOIN article_module_map amm ON amm.article = afm.article 
        WHERE afm.organization = 4 AND 
            amm.module = 2 
    )
```

What I am doing in the above query is first truncating the list of articles to the selected module, and then further truncating that list to the articles that are not in the subquery. The subquery is generating a list of the articles that an organization has already uploaded PDF's for. Hence, the end result is a list of articles that an organization has not yet uploaded PDF's for.

Help would be hugely appreciated, thanks in advance!

**EDIT 2012/10/25**

With @fthiella's help, the below query ran in an astonishing 1.02 seconds, down from 37+ seconds!

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT article.* FROM article 
    INNER JOIN article_module_map
        ON article.id = article_module_map.article
    WHERE article_module_map.module = 2
) AS a
LEFT JOIN article_file_map
    ON a.id = article_file_map.article
    AND article_file_map.organization=4
WHERE article_file_map.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Instead of showing all articles in the same page I think a good method is to implement a pagination script.. and show just 20-30 rows for each page.. this will be more faster

Comment: did you try and see explain plan for this? what are your keys? try reversing the order of tables in you joins too

Comment: Do you have indexes on the database table on a.id, amm.article, afm.article?

Comment: indexing field names would do the trick and do not use * in select clause. select field by their names

Comment: @Adder, I'm not sure if I've done it right, but I have a.id marked as a primary key and added as an index, and have added an index for amm.article and afm.article as well. It does not seem to have changed the performance. The query still takes 40+ seconds to complete. If that should bring it from 40 seconds to 0.05 seconds, then maybe I did it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that i can understand the logic and the structure of the tables correctly. This is my query:

```
SELECT
  article.id
FROM
  article
    INNER JOIN
  article_module_map
    ON article.id = article_module_map.article
    AND article_module_map.module=2
  LEFT JOIN
    article_file_map
    ON article.id = article_file_map.article
    AND article_file_map.organization=4
WHERE
  article_file_map.id IS NULL
```

I extract all of the articles that have a module 2. I then select those that organization 4 didn't provide a file.

I used a LEFT JOIN instead of a subquery. In some circumstances this could be faster.

**EDIT** Thank you for your comment. I wasn't sure it would run faster, but it surprises me that it is so much slower! Anyway, it was worth a try!

Now, out of curiosity, I would like to try all the combinations of LEFT/INNER JOIN and subquery, to see which one runs faster, eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     article INNER JOIN article_module_map
     ON article.id = article_module_map.article
   WHERE
     article_module_map.module=2)
  LEFT JOIN
etc.
```

maybe removing *, and I would like to see what changes between the condition on the WHERE clause and on the ON clause... anyway I think it doesn't help much, you should concentrate on indexes now.

Indexes on keys/foreign key should be okay already, but what if you add an index on `article_module_map.module` and/or `article_file_map.organization` ?

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts! Your query works spot on, so you've done a great job figuring things out. Unfortunately however, it takes 72 seconds to execute as opposed to mine which takes 37 seconds. Note, I replaced the SELECT in your query with SELECT *, purely for comparing execution times. In my final go, I will replace it with the required fields only.

Comment: your edited query brought the execution time from 37+ seconds to 1 second... you are my hero! I included the revised query in my original post, with the only change being that I specified the fields in the SELECT statement to only the ones I need. Thank you again!!

Comment: i'm happy to know that my edited query is much faster now :) thanks! i have some suspects, but it's not easy explain why it runs faster... they look very similar! the only thing to do in these cases is to try to rewrite the query and to try to group tables using a different approach!

Answer (score 1):

When optimizing queries I use to check the following points:

First: I would avoid using * in SELECT clause, instead, name the diferent fields you want. This increases crazily the speed (I had one which took 7 seconds with *, and naming the field decreased to 0.1s).

Second: As @Adder says, add indexes to your tables.

Third: Try using INNER JOIN instead of WHERE amm.module = 2 AND a.id NOT IN ( ... ). I think I  read (I don't remember it well, so take it carefully) that usually MySQL optimize INNER JOINS, and as your subquery is a filter, maybe using three INNER JOINS plus WHERE would be faster to retrieve.

Comment: Wouldn't an INNER JOIN only return the articles present in both tables? I'm trying to achieve a result that only includes results NOT in the article_file_map table that ARE in the article_module_map table, so an INNER JOIN would give me all of the articles that already have PDFs, rather than the ones that don't. It seems like the possible join I would want is a LEFT JOIN, however, due to the fact that I need to check for PDF's only uploaded by a certain organization, this method hasn't helped me either. The only way I've been able to capture all of the criteria is using the subquery.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you have checked query submitted by @fthiella, (I've just done it) but maybe his query is faster than yours, and is returning the needed data. Anyway, did you try the points I wrote you? It is improving, or is the same? I keep thinking that your main problem is * and indexes, and then, subquery.